# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre :before y ::before?

Tags: css, css3

En varios ejemplos en internet he encontrado que utilizan a veces :before y otras veces ::before

```
div::before {
  content: 'bla ';
}

div:before {
  content: 'bla ';
}
```

Los probé ambos y siempre me funcionan, entonces no entiendo si hay alguna diferencia (o no), o cuál de los dos debería usar, o si realmente no importa y puedo usar ambos en cualquier situación.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `::before` (dos veces los dos puntos) es la "versión" CSS3 del pseudoelemento.
- `:before` (una vez los dos puntos) es la "versión" CSS2.1 del pseudoelemento.

La diferencia en términos de código:

```
/* CSS3 */
div::before {
  content: 'bla ';
}

/* CSS2.1 */
div:before {
  content: 'bla ';
}
```

Las dos sintaxis se pueden usar en todos los navegadores modernos y en IE a partir de la versión 9. IE8 solo acepta `:before`, y versiones anteriores (IE7, IE6) que en teoría ya no deberían existir (o utilizarse), no lo soportan.

La versión de CSS3 fue creada para diferenciar los [pseudoelementos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudoelementos) de las [pseudoclases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), manteniendo estas últimas la sintaxis de CSS2.1 (una vez los dos puntos).

A continuación la definición de la sintaxis de `:before` en CSS2.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/generate.html#before-after-content

En la especificación de CSS3, en la sección de cambios con respecto a CSS2 se ve reflejado: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#changesFromCSS2

Y por último la especificación de `::before` en CSS3: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#gen-content